# Fixture.Customize vs Fixture.Register

Tags: autofixture

Please explain the functional difference between `Customize` and `Register`, when to use one over the other.  The `TestCustomize` example below fails and the `TestRegister` passes.  I expected the customize script to work fine.  It reads to me in English as:
"When generating an `HttpClient`, use a post-processing lambda on it before providing the specimen".

But what I get is an HTTP address with a GUID in it, clearly generated by AutoFixture.

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestCustomize()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customize<HttpClient>(c =>
    {
        //c.OmitAutoProperties(); makes no difference
        c.Do(x => x.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myval"));
        return c;
    });
    var client = fixture.Create<HttpClient>();
    Assert.Equal("http://myval/", client.BaseAddress.ToString());
}

[Fact]
public void TestRegister()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Register(() => new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myval")
    });
    var client = fixture.Create<HttpClient>();
    Assert.Equal("http://myval/", client.BaseAddress.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I reworked the question after finding some time to do so.  Hopefully you can identify the concepts I'm missing here and help out a little, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Customize` vs. `Register`. In fact, if you look at the [source code for `Register`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/a1e9beef03412ebe437b401628b4d003deaa59d9/Src/AutoFixture/FixtureRegistrar.cs#L94-L99), you'll see that it's only a convenience method over `Customize`.

The problem lies in the use of `Do`. If you look at the signature of `Do`, you'll see that it has this type:

```
IPostprocessComposer<T> Do(Action<T> action)
```

Notice that the method returns a value. In Functional style, or, if you will, following [Command-Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation), the method doesn't mutate the instance on which it's defined, but rather returns a new object with the changed behaviour.

When one writes:

```
c.Do(x => x.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myval"));
```

one immediately discards the return value with the changed behaviour. In languages like F# or Haskell, you'd get a compile-time notification if you wrote code like that, telling you that you'd be ignoring the return value of a function call, but C# doesn't do that.

In any case, AutoFixture's APIs are designed as [fluent interfaces](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html). The intent is that you chain method calls together:

```
fixture.Customize<HttpClient>(c => c
    .Without(x => x.BaseAddress)
    .Do(x => x.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myval")));
```

You still need `Without` (or, if you will, `OmitAutoProperties`) to turn off the default auto-property behaviour, because otherwise, `BaseAddress` will be overwritten by the auto-property feature.

This version of the test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void TestCustomize()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customize<HttpClient>(c => c
        .Without(x => x.BaseAddress)
        .Do(x => x.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myval")));

    var client = fixture.Create<HttpClient>();

    Assert.Equal("http://myval/", client.BaseAddress.ToString());
}
```